# Simple string compression reloaded

Tags: c, compression

Inspired by [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115538/algorithm-for-simple-string-compression) I thought I provide my implementation. I tried to go with the spirit of the *nix tool chain - read from stdin and write to stdout. This has the added benefit of making buffering very easy (current and previous characters and the count).

All kinds of reviews welcome (best practices, error handling, weird edge cases, potential bugs or other pitfalls).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void write_char(int c)
{
    if (EOF == putchar(c))
    {
        if (ferror(stdout)) 
        {
            perror("error writing char to stdout");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

void write_count(uint64_t count)
{
    if (printf("%ull", count) < 0)
    {
        perror("error writing character count to stdout");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int current_char = 0;
    int previous_char = 0;
    uint64_t current_char_count = 0;

    while (EOF != (current_char = getchar())
    {
        if (current_char_count == 0 || current_char_count == UINT64_MAX || previous_char != current_char)
        {
            if (current_char_count > 0)
            {
                write_count(current_char_count);
            }
            write_char(current_char);
            current_char_count = 1;
            previous_char = current_char;
        }
        else
        {
            current_char_count += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has been [mentioned on Meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6425/9357).

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115763/simple-compression-reloaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Compressor number or real

When you are `write_count`ing, you are writing the ASCII number characters to the new file. However, when you go to decompress this file, how are you going to differentiate between the actual content in the file and the numbers that mark the occurrences of a character?

A possible solution for this might be to just write the number itself to the file (no ASCII). That way, when you encounter a number that is ASCII, you can be almost sure that the number is part of the content (that is, unless there was a letter that occurred so many times in a row that the counter rose into the `'0'-'9'` range).

---

### Two ones or twelve?

This is kind of a continuation from the top one. Let's say your compressor went to go compress this file:

> 12

Now, I am ready to decompress it. Since your compressor writes a number to show occurrences of a character, the output would be this:

> 1121

How do I know if all of those numbers are part of the content?

The only fix I can think of, unfortunately, would be to follow the above tip and write `0x01` instead of an ASCII number.

---

## Misc

> ```
> while (EOF != (current_char = getchar())
> ```

You are missing a brace here.

---

> ```
> if (printf("%ull", count) < 0)
> ```

When compiling your code, I get this on this line:

> ```
> warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint64_t’ [-Wformat=]
> ```

This also showed a problem that two `l`s are written after the number that shows how many character occurrences there were.

Comment: Regarding your Misc bugs: must have copied accidentally an older version of the code. Sorry about that, should have  checked more carefully.  Good point about the number encoding, got some ideas about that.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.

For gcc, at a minimum, use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (I also use `-std=c99 -Wconversion`)

The compiler outputs several 'problem' statements:

To start: the `main()` function signature of `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`  which in this case should be `int main( void )`.

> ```
> unused parameter `argc`
> unused parameter `argv`
> ```

And, because of a missing `#include <stdlib.h>` statement:

> ```
> implicit declaration of function: `exit()`
> EXIT_FAILURE not declared
> ```

And this line:

```
while (EOF != (current_char = getchar())
```

has a syntax error (always check for matching numbers of open and close parens):

> error: expected ')' before '{'

That error means the posted code was never compiled.

Comment: As I've stated as comment to SirPython's answer: I accidentally copied an broken code version.